# ARM placing byte address in little endian

Tags: assembly, arm

I have this bytes

`DCB 0xC1, 0x0A, 0xFC, 0x15, 0xFF, 0x07`

I have to place it in memory using little endian, and the memory address of `0xC1` is `0x00400070`

Then I have doing this but dont know if its correct:

```
0x0040070 => 15 FC 0A C1
0x0040074 => 00 00 07 FF
```

I mean, if its only 1 byte, I dont have to use any order?
I know its different when I use half-words or words but I have this doubt.

Comment: The `DCB` declares bytes, so they don't care about endianness, they are stored in the order as you write them. But then at address `0x0040070` will be `0xC1`, not `0x15` - just as you declared them in `DCB`. If you will then read half-word from `0x0040070`, it will be either `0xC10A` (big-endian) or `0x0AC1` (little-endian), but that depends what mode is used to read the half-word.

Comment: yeah, but the bytes doesnt grow from right to left? I mean Where I put the `C1` is the `0x0040070`, `0A` is the `0x0040074`, ...

Comment: No, the memory is byte-addressed. The `DCB` will set one byte at time. Starting at `0x0040070` it will set it to `C1`, the next address is `0x0040071`, set to `0A`, then `0x0040072` is set to `FC`, etc... there's nothing "growing from right to left", maybe you are referring to some debug visual output, but if you will check the memory view in bytes, you will see them in the `DCB` order. If you will check little-endian word view, then you will see at address `0x0040070` value `0x15FC0AC1` (and big-endian word would produce `0xC10AFC15`), but underlying bytes are `C1 0A FC 15 FF ...`

Comment: So when I place one byte at time, I have to place it in normal order, I mean in my case `C1 0A FC 15 FF ...` But if it would be word of halfword(DCD or DCW) then I would have to consider if I want little endian or big endian? I mean if I have `DCW 6`, I would have to place it as `06 00` in little endian case.

Comment: Usually the target platform decides the endianness, and the assembler is pre-configured to follow that. So when you write *WORD* constant `0x11223344` in the source, the assembler will translate it in the configured/expected way (either `44 33 ...` or `11 22 ...`) to hide the endianness fuss from you. If you are working in truly bi-endian environment, where the same source is to be used in both modes, then you will have to think about it and use some preprocessor or assembler options and write code in a bit more constrained way to not hit endianness specific byte order anywhere in code.

Comment: So in my case I have to assume little endian, its an exam exercise so then  I have to write it as `0x0040070`=> `C1 0A FC 15` for that would be read as `0x15FC0AC1`

Comment: And If I have                                                                                                      `DCD 0xC1, 0x0A, 0xFC, 0x15, 0xFF, 0x07`                                                           `DCW 6`                                                                                                                    It will be `0x0040070` => `C1 0A FC 15` and `0x0040074`=>`FF 07 06 00`?

Comment: Yes, with assembler using little-endian way to convert half-word into bytes, which it probably does, as you asked first about it. Then in code, if you read `0x0040074` as full word, with little-endian configured CPU it will read `0x000607FF` (i.e. mixing `DCB` and `DCW` to create `DCD`-like definition). When unsure, just write it in the source, assemble, and check in debugger memory view + result of desired fetch instruction.